# Render a page after its layout is fully mounted in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using a layout for my admin pages which brings user informations in a layout, so I don't have to query user information every time the page changes.

However, the problem is, when I query user information in layout, the page does not wait for the layout to load.

***myLayout.vue***

```
beforeMount() {
    // getting user info from the server by Vuex action
}
```

***myPage.vue***

```
layout: "myLayout"
...
mounted() {
    // bring user info from the Vuex store
}
```

In this case, I expect `beforeMount` to be done in `myLayout.vue`,

but `myPage.vue` does not wait and get `mounted` before Vuex action is completed.

so the lifecycle would be

`layout's beforeMount` -> `page's beforeMount` -> `page's mounted` -> `layout's mounted`

because page does not wait for beforeMount of a layout to be done.

Is there a way to prevent a page to be mounted before layout is mounted?

Comment: Problem is not in the order of hook calls. Problem is your async action in Vuex store started in `beforeMount`. It's not possible to simply wait for async call (promise) in JS - you need to work around it...ie. write all components in a way that data is not here on 1st render and will become available later...

Comment: Have you considered `nuxtServerInit`? is that a possibility for you?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the problem is, that I am doing the authentication with middlewares. Therefore, if I use `nuxtServerInit` to bring user information, it would fail because the authentication is not done yet. If possible, I don't want to rebuild the whole structure.

Comment: i think simple solution is asyncData, you should use this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `middleware` on your Layout, that will pretty much run before the layout and therefore, your page.

```js
export default {
  ...
  async middleware({ store }) {
    await store.dispatch('fetch-some-data-with-vuex')
  },
  ...
}
```

More infos here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/middleware/

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved it.

The nuxt component which renders the page is mounted after the loading is complete. This is achieved using a variable and a conditional statement.

*layout.vue*

```
<template>
  <Nuxt v-if="hasLoaded" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      hasLoaded: false,
    }
  },
  async created () {
    // do stuff

    this.hasLoaded = true;
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be :

In your layout ( *myLayout.vue* ) emit an event after you load your data

```
this.$root.$emit('layout_loaded', true);
```

Now you have to listen for this event in your page ( *myPage.vue* )

```
mounted(){
    this.$root.$on('layout_loaded', (state) => {
        // bring user info from the Vuex store
    });
}
```

Comment: This solution helped me a lot.  The middleware answer great if you are not using SSR.  The other 'mounted' answer would lock up the server render of pages that didn't need authorization checks.